# Different code formatter for development and SVN commit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm forced to use very strange Java code formatter. Unfortunately I can't modify this formatter. So is it somehow possible to have my formatter active during development (e.g. on save action) and change the formatter to the "proper" one just before commit or any time with simple shortcut? Is there any eclipse function or plug-in for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot apply two formatters for different purposes. But you can apply two formatters to two copies of the code.

So you might try this: Apply your own formatter to your local working copy, and add an [Ant builder](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-93_project_builder.htm) to the builder list in your project settings. That Ant builder will be triggered together with the normal Java build on every source change. Have the Ant file of the Ant builder copy your original project recursively into a second project in the same workspace, but exclude the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.*.pref` files (which contain the Java settings). Make sure to have the "Refresh resources" option applied in the Ant Builder. Now apply the SVN formatter to the second project.

When you need to checkin, you probably still have to run `Source -> Format` once on the second project node manually before submitting.

**Alternative: Server side SVN hook**

You could also apply the formatting on the SVN server, controlled by a hook on submitting your changes. However, this requires you to be able to administrate that server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple Code Formatter profiles in Eclipse.

> Go to Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter

Click on **New** to create a Profile and then click **Edit** to modify that profile. Here you can modify the formatter the way you want. Once done, you can even export it, so other members of your project can import and use this profile. Thus all your SVN commits will have the same Formatting.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can have multiple formatters, but when you select one formatter then this formatter will be used always - on save action, during SVN commit, etc.. My questions is, can I use different formatters for every operation, e.g. one on save action and another on SVN commit?